# How to add timestamp watermark while recording video?

Tags: ios, swift, video-capture, video-recording

I'm making iOS video recording app using AVFoundation. Every frame of a video should have timestamp showing time when the video frame was recorded.  I looked internet but could not find any reasonable articles.

Here is my current code around video record.

```
    private var session = AVCaptureSession()
    private let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    private let audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()

    private func setupCaptureSession() {
        session.sessionPreset = .vga640x480

        guard
            let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video),
            let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio),
            let videoInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice),
            let audioInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice) else {
            fatalError()
        }

        session.beginConfiguration()
        session.addInput(videoInput)
        session.addInput(audioInput)
        session.addOutput(videoOutput)
        session.addOutput(audioOutput)
        session.commitConfiguration()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let previewView = PreviewView()
            previewView.videoPreviewLayer.session = self.session
            previewView.videoPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
            previewView.frame = self.view.bounds
            previewView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            self.compositeImageView.insertSubview(previewView, at: 0)

            self.session.startRunning()
        }
    }

    private func startRecording() {
        // AVAssetWriter
        assetWriter = try! AVAssetWriter(outputURL: self.exportURL!, fileType: .mov)

        // video
        let videoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: [
            AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.h264,
            AVVideoWidthKey : 640,
            AVVideoHeightKey : 480
        ])
        videoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        assetWriter?.add(videoInput)

        // audio
        let audioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: nil)
        audioInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        assetWriter?.add(audioInput)

        assetWriter?.startWriting()

        let queue = DispatchQueue.global()
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
        audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    }

    private func finishRecording() {
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(nil, queue: nil)
        audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(nil, queue: nil)

        startTime = nil

        assetWriter?.finishWriting { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            guard self.assetWriter!.status == .completed else { fatalError("failed recording") }

            self.saveToPhotoLibrary { isSaveToPhotoLibrarySucceed in
                print("vide saved to photo library")
                
                guard isSaveToPhotoLibrarySucceed else {
                    print("Save to photo library failed")
                    return
                }
                
                self.saveToRealmFromTempVideo {
                    self.uploadVideoToServer()
                }
            }
        }
    }

     func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        guard isRecording else { fatalError() }

        guard CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) else {
            print("not ready")
            return
        }

        if startTime == nil {
            startTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
            assetWriter?.startSession(atSourceTime: startTime!)
        }

        // Append video or audio
        
        let mediaType: AVMediaType = output is AVCaptureVideoDataOutput ? .video : .audio
        
        if mediaType == .video {
            appendVideo(from: sampleBuffer)
        } else if mediaType == .audio {
            appendAudio(from: sampleBuffer)
        } else {
            fatalError("should not reach here")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it the "startTime" that should be added to frames?